# error C2003: expected 'defined id'

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I made a mechanism for compiling only selected tests from a sequence of tests by defining the macros:

```
#define SELECTION(x) ((!defined (RUN_SELECTED_TESTS_ONLY)) || (defined (x)))

#define RUN_SELECTED_TESTS_ONLY
#define TEST_1                  //Lets say I want only test1 to be compiled

#if SELECTION(TEST_1)           //The line I'm getting the error on.
     //code of test 1
#endif

 #if SELECTION(TEST_2)
     //code of test 2
#endif
```

While compilation I'm getting the error :

> error C2003: expected 'defined id'

I'm getting the error only when TEST_1 or TEST_2 (or both) are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative definition for `SELECTION`:

```
#ifdef RUN_SELECTED_TESTS_ONLY
    #define SELECTION defined
#else
    #define SELECTION(x) 1
#endif
```

Notes:

- Must be defined *after* `RUN_SELECTED_TESTS_ONLY` is.
- Only works in GNU cpp and other preprocessors [similarly permissive](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html) about operator `defined` being the result of a macro expansion.

Example:

```
#define RUN_SELECTED_TESTS_ONLY

#ifdef RUN_SELECTED_TESTS_ONLY
#define SELECTION defined
#else
#define SELECTION(x) 1
#endif

#define TEST_1
//#define TEST_2

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
#if SELECTION(TEST_1)
        printf("Test 1\n");
#endif
#if SELECTION(TEST_2)
        printf("Test 2\n");
#endif
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Test 1
```

Comment: The alternative is working :). But, do you have any Idea why the original doesn't compile?

Comment: It's *undefined* to define **defined** operator as it can't appear as a replacement.

Comment: @BlueMoon: Good point; my solution may only work in gcc. From [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html): "If the defined operator appears as a result of a macro expansion, the C standard says the behavior is undefined. GNU cpp treats it as a genuine defined operator and evaluates it normally. It will warn wherever your code uses this feature if you use the command-line option -pedantic, since other compilers may handle it differently."

Comment: @Sanich: The original `SELECTION` macro performs an exhaustive macro expansion on `x`. In your case, `TEST_1` evaluates to an empty string, resulting in `defined ()` which is syntactically incorrect. A workaround would be a recursive definition: `#define TEST_1 TEST_1`. The preprocessor will stop macro expansion right there, to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: @Ruud: "In your case, TEST_1 evaluates to an empty string" - why?

Comment: @Sanich: `#define TEST_1` has no replacement token list, meaning every instance of `TEST_1` is replaced by the empty string. This is what happens when `#if SELECTION(TEST_1)` is expanded. It does _not_ happen in `#if defined(TEST_1)` because `defined` is a special preprocessor operator. I know it is confusing; it's not surprising C standard banned this usage of `defined`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have invokes *undefined behaviour*. C standard says that the **defined** preprocessor operator may not appear as a result of replacement.

**C11 draft, 6.10.1 Conditional inclusion**

> 4 Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing
>   tokens that will become the controlling constant expression are
>   replaced (except for those macro names modified by the defined unary
>   operator), just as in normal text. **If the token defined is generated
>   as a result of this replacement process or use of the defined unary
>   operator does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro
>   replacement, the behavior is undefined**. After all replacements due to
>   macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed,
>   all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to
>   keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0, and then each
>   preprocessing token is converted into a token.

If you can't perform same check at run-time, you could do:

```
#define RUN_SELECTED_TESTS_ONLY
#define TEST_1

#if ((!defined (RUN_SELECTED_TESTS_ONLY)) || (defined (TEST_1)))
     //code of test 1
#endif
```

Basically performing the "selection" yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get means: *An identifier must follow the preprocessor keyword.* (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts2ba83w.aspx)).
It doesn't work because you cannot you `defined()` 2 times in your macro `SELECTION(x)`.

What you can do instead is something like:

```
#define SELECTION(x) (!RUN_SELECTED_TESTS_ONLY || x)

#define RUN_SELECTED_TESTS_ONLY 1
#define TEST_1 1
#define TEST_2 0

#if SELECTION(TEST_1)
     //some code
#endif

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", SELECTION(TEST_1));
    printf("%d\n", SELECTION(TEST_2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've read the MSDN note about it. How can you understand from it that the problem is using define() twice?

Comment: True, the MSDN note is a bit laconic.

Comment: And, this proposal is not good enough for me because if I have 1000 tests I will have to define 1000 macros :)

Comment: No, you would only have to define 1000 `TEST_*` variables. But you could also change your code to use `int tests[1000]` :)

Comment: Each test has an unique name and not numbered as in my simple example. It would be hard to associate place in array with a specific test. :)